# What is the "//= require bootstrap/affix" notation for? Is there any grunt tool that uses it?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Lately I switched from `bootstrap-sass` repository to `bootstrap-sass-official` and I noticed something unfamiliar in the [bootstrap.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/v3.1.1/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js) file, namely:

```
//= require bootstrap/affix
//= require bootstrap/alert
//= require bootstrap/button
//= require bootstrap/carousel
//= require bootstrap/collapse
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require bootstrap/tab
//= require bootstrap/transition
//= require bootstrap/scrollspy
//= require bootstrap/modal
//= require bootstrap/tooltip
//= require bootstrap/popover
```

I understand this is to include just one file (bootstrap.js) which tells us to require (import) the partials from bootstrap directory. However, this is for sure not part of native Javascript, and I couldn't find on google what is it.

Can anyone enlighten me and tell what piece of software should understand this notation and is reponsible for building/getting the partials code? Or is this just a simple comment (if it is.. why on earth create a seperate file for this?)?

EDIT: I use grunt to build my assets. Is there any grunt tool that uses this notation or do I simply ignore it and reference partials in my layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loostro, this is something that Ruby on Rails would look for, to compile assets in a specific order. The //= notation lets Sprockets know to include those files. You can learn more about this part of Rails, called the Asset Pipeline, here: [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset%5fpipeline.html), or with Hartl's perfect intro guide, here: [http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-sass_and_the_asset_pipeline](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-sass%5fand%5fthe%5fasset%5fpipeline)

Comment: I use grunt to build my assets. Is there any grunt tool that uses this notation or do I simply ignore it and reference partials in my layout?

Comment: I'm not familiar with grunt, but I think I can point you in the right direction. The //= notation lets Sprockets know to include those files, and it looks like grunt works with sprockets sometimes, here: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-sprockets-directives.